# PyQt: app.exec_() stops all following code from running

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a code which looks like:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
self.interface = Interface()

# The figure
self.fig = self.interface.fig
self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

self.interface.show()
app.exec_()

print 'this is not printed'
```

The problem is that once `app.exec_()` is executed, nothing is until I close the window that pops up.

How can I continue running the code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is intended. What you have to do is use signals/slots, code inside your Qt classes, or spawn off threads before you call app.exec().

Signals and slots are your defacto way of interacting with Qt. Basically a signal is any "event" or custom "event" and slots can be thought of as "event handlers". For instance when someone hits a button on a GUI it creates a signal that seeks out any handler that is connected to it. You can connect none, one, or many slots to each signal (you can even connect the same one multiple times)! [Here is a good reference](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Python_introduction_to_signals_and_slots) for this in python.

Coding inside your Qt classes usually means creating slots that do useful work for you. Remember you don't want to hold up the event loop too long so spawn a new thread if you do this.

The third option available to you is to spin off other threads. Be careful interacting with Qt from threads, if you do you MUST us signals and slots. Implement threading as [suggested in this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm quite new to this, so could you please explain in a bit more detail what I should do or at least point me out to some online example? PyQt examples are pretty scarce, unfortunately...

Comment: Let me know if you run into more trouble. Basically app.exec() is supposed to lock everything up and you have to work around it.

Comment: so bottom line, there is no chance of running code past `app.exec_()`? Is it possible to just open a window, do some stuff, close it, and then run code past that point?

Comment: I've never done it, but all indicates point to yes, just make sure whatever you use to close it calls the correct Qt signal for closing. Otherwise Qt closes very messily and you probably won't get that function to return.

Answer (score 10):

`app.exec_()` does not lock anything, it runs a GUI event loop that waits for user actions (events) and dispatches them to the right widget for handling. It does this until there are no top level windows left open; if you leave at least one top level window of your app open, then exec() never returns, it can't (your app will be terminated during system shutdown). When no more top level windows the app cleans up and returns from `exec()`. At that point the GUI is no longer in the event loop.

Whatever it is you want to do after `exec()` it is likely you would either put it in a QThread or in a signal handler (which you would connect, for example, to a "Go!" button; you would connect a "Cancel" button to a handler that closes the app window).

You can put code after `exec()` but it would be rather unconventional: if anything goes wrong it is unlikely that user can see the problem since the GUI is no longer visible, a GUI app doesn't usually have a console terminal open where the error might be seen, there will not typically be a console for a GUI app (ie you will run the app via `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`), or you have to open a new window and exec() again in order to show an error message and wait till user clicks ok, destroy message window in ok handler so `app.exec()` once again returns.

Comment: Is there a signal evoked after the gui starts?

Comment: There are a dozen signals emitted by QApplication, one of them might do the trick (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html). There may be some event methods of QMainWindow (most of them defined in QWidget) that you could trap (by overriding method). Post a specific question on SO for more details.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous answer, not every time when all windows are closed does the GUI event loop, run by `app.exec_()`, stop. If you want to terminate it manually you can use `app.quit()` inside any of the event handlers. It stops GUI event loop and launches your code after `app.exec_()`.

First answer is a lot of words about nothing.

Answer (score 2):

A dirty trick to remove blocking would be to abuse mathplot lib:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib as mpl

import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.collections as mcol
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm       # colors 
from   mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D   # imports options for 3-D plotting
from   matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
# ============================================================== 
if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
else:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 
#endelse

MainWindow =  QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
MainWindow=uic.loadUi('E:\Python\Python_lib\MyGui.ui',MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

# There are two ways to start the gui, and i.e. it looping 
# The correct way if to use app.exec_(), which 
# blocks the command line :


#d=app.exec_()

# However, this will block the command line making 
# We can misuse mathplot lib creating a Figure instead
# which seems to start the Gui loop without blocking the command line: 

ImageFig = Figure((3,4))
ImagePanel = FigureCanvas(ImageFig)
ImagePanel.draw()
```