# Python, Qt5 GUI App, and asyncio results in program not closing when window closed

Tags: python, pyqt, python-asyncio

I have an application I am working on which has a Qt GUI made to control a gRPC back end.  I prefer using python-betterproto to process the gRPC .proto files, however these classes use asyncio.  After a lot of searching, the only solution I found that allows my Qt Application Class to send signals back and forth between my backend application class was

- have my backend class inherit from QtCore.QObject
- use QEventLoop and asyncSlot from asyncqt
- and launch the application as follows

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
loop = QEventLoop(app)
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
window = Ui()
app.exec()
with loop:
    loop.run_forever()
```

The application is working, and signals can be connected to slots in both directions.  However, when I close the GUI Window, the application is still running, I assume because I told the loop to 'run_forever()'

How can I make this event loop stop listening when the application closes?

Comment: remove `app.exec()`. Also provide a [mre]

Comment: Yes, this works. For trying to figure out why, I took a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142719/pyqt-app-exec-stops-all-following-code-from-running

It seems that app.exec() runs the event loop also. In my code, I pulled out the event loop so asyncio and Qt could share it (i think) which means I was running it twice.